# How to save a file to Azure Storage Account through App Service?

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-appservice

I am new to Azure. What I am **trying to do is upload a file to Azure Storage Account** from  a **spring boot** application running inside a **Azure App Function** (using **Azure App Service**)?

The **code** I am using **to get the Azure Credentials**

```java
DefaultAzureCredential defaultCredential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build();
```

but this code throws **exception**:

```
Result: Failure Exception: CredentialUnavailableException: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. 
Environment variables are not fully configured.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting 
guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot Managed Identity 
authentication is not available. SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were 
found in the cache. IntelliJ Authentication not available. Please log in with Azure Tools for IntelliJ plugin 
in the IDE. AzureCliCredential authentication unavailable. Azure CLI not installed.To mitigate this issue, 
please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/azclicredential/troubleshoot 
Azure PowerShell authentication failed using defaultpowershell(pwsh) with following error: Unable to execute 
PowerShell. Please make sure that it is installed in your system. Azure PowerShell authentication failed using powershell-core(powershell) with following error: Encountered error when deserializing response from Azure Power Shell.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azure-identity-java-default-azure-credential-troubleshoot Stack: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
```

If I try to run this **locally then there is no problem**, but **in the Azure App Service it throws this error**.

Can anybody help me regarding adding the right code to get the credentials?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't have Managed Identity turned on for the Api Function (and App Service which will inherit Api Function's Managed Identity)

1. To turn this on you need to navigate through the sidebar to Identity

   [image]
2. Then you need to turn System Assigned status On
   [image]
3. Then you need to assign the required role which was "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
   [image]

Caution: I added "Contributor" role instead of "Storage Blob Data Contributor" which didn't worked and gave me 403. My thinking here was it will be more superior role but didn't work that way.
[image]